# Determine if Shift key is pressed during mousedown event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to determine whether the Shift key is pressed during a mousedown d3.event? if possible could show me a way to do this, try looking in the API, but could not find something useful

Comment: I have no experience with d3, but, you could just listen for keyboard events then whenever shift is pressed start a mouse event listener.

Comment: Are you using any other libraries?

Comment: not at the moment I'm only using d3.js

Comment: Please see my below answer. My previous one mistakenly used `function(e)`, you can't do that with d3.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
d3.select(window).on("click", function() {
    if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
        alert("Mouse+Shift pressed");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/NTGKG/1/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is necessary to use:

```
if (d3.event.sourceEvent.shiftKey) {
  console.log("shift pressed");
}
```