# Ho do I capture ctrl + click on MacOS with d3js

Tags: javascript, macos, d3.js, cross-browser, browserstack

I got a report that my script which should trigger on `ctrl + click` does not work on Mac.

Like shown in "[Determine if Shift key is pressed during mousedown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518741/determine-if-shift-key-is-pressed-during-mousedown-event)" we can determine if modifier keys are pressed during a mouse click testing `d3.event.shiftKey`, `d3.event.ctrlKey` etc. The `shift` detection works everywhere but `ctrl` does not seem to work on MacOS.

```js
d3.select(window).on("click", function() {
    if (d3.event.ctrlKey) {
        alert("Mouse + Ctrl pressed");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I don't have a Mac but I tested the script above using BrowserStack with:

- Mavericks with Safari 7.1, Firefox 54 and Chrome 60;
- Sierra with Safari 10.1, Firefox 54 and Chrome 60

It is not working with any of the browsers on Mac. It works fine on Windows and Linux though.

What do I do wrong? Is the ctrl key some kind of a special key on Mac OSes (I suppose it is as Mac has also the 'command' key). Is using the `ctrl + click` discouraged for Mac OS compatibility?

Edit: I found this one: "[any way to detect ctrl + click in javascript for osx browsers? no jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725824/any-way-to-detect-ctrl-click-in-javascript-for-osx-browsers-no-jquery)". My questions still holds as using d3.js framework I would expect that there is a way to do this in a cross-browser compatible way using `d3.event`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this in the following way:

```
if (d3.event.ctrlKey || d3.event.metaKey) {
    alert("Mouse + Ctrl pressed (or command key for Mac users)");
}
```